# Android Wear MessageApi vs ChannelApi

Tags: android, wear-os, channel-api

Android Wear offers multiple ways to synchronize data between the handheld device and the smartwatch. I would like to know when you are supposed to use the [MessageApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi) and when to use the [ChannelApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/ChannelApi)?

When I was first encountered the problem I wanted to use the MessageApi as it is suggested on the Android developer [Sending and Receiving Messages](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) website. However, there is written that the MessageApi is not reliability:

> **Note:** A successful result code does not guarantee delivery of the message. If your app requires data reliability, use DataItem objects or the ChannelApi class to send data between devices.

Therefore I use the ChannelApi to send String messages as a byte array between the handheld device and the smartwatch. But why should you even use the MessageApi when it is not reliable?

Comment: why would you use udp instead of tcp ?

Comment: So the Message API is UDP based and the Channel API is TCP based? If it is like that, does the Message API send the message in ordered packages or do I have to check for that by myself?

Comment: No they are not. My question was to put a little bit of emphasis on the fact that for the sake of simplicity we are ready to accept to loose some of the information we send

Comment: But what kind of simplicity is it in that case? Does the Message API use a simpler way to send messages like UDP does? What exactly is the advantage of the Message API compared to the Channel API?

Comment: I think I just found the solution by myself. I just had a look again on the implementation of both APIs. The Message API has the sendMessage method to send messages. The API describes that data are generally not larger than 100k. The Channel API on the other side uses an OutputStream to send data. That means that I can use a stream instead to send the data all at once :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ChannelApi, if you want to send data in a stream. Use the MessageApi to avoid streams => this has a better performance for small messages.